problema al procesar script php en la misma página para envio de formulario
Cordial saludo, agradezco la oportunidad de ayudarme con este tema, estoy realizando un sistema de información en php, tengo un inconveniente, estoy intentando enviar unos datos a través de un formulario en un modal, quiero que el script se procese en la misma pagina, pero cuando envío el formulario muestra una página de "not found", como sino encontrara la pagina en la cual se esta procesando el envío de los datos.
Aclaración: en una misma pagina tengo dos ventanas modales, en una se abre un formulario "AsignarAsignatura.php" y en el otro modal se abre "CrearPensum.php", la estructura del código es casi que la misma en los dos modales la diferencia son los campos que los componen y las variables declaradas que les he cambiado nombres para que no entren en conflicto, si pruebo uno funciona bien de manera independiente es decir quitando el código de referencia al otro modal, y si pruebo el otro haciendo lo mismo funciona bien pero como les digo siendo un único modal en la pagina. como mencioné he cambiado el nombre de algunas variables que se han declarado en el codigo para que no generen conflicto ya que los dos modales están en el misma pagina principal.
la redirección va hacia un pagina llamada Programa.php a través de un id que ya ha sido captado previamente ya que los modals se encuentran en la misma pagina y no hay problema con eso.
Este es el codigo: la pagina modal se llama AsignarAsignatura.php ---> mas adelante comparto también el código del otro modal donde la pagina se llama CrearPensum.php "
<?php
// Incluimos la conexión existente con la DB.
require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
// Se captan en las variables los datos provenientes de los campos del formulario.  

if(!empty($_POST)){

// Se crea la consulta a la tabla para hacer la validación y comparación de los datos.
$consultaRg2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbpensumcontenido WHERE Pensum = :codPensum && asignatura = :nombreAsig LIMIT 1;");
$consultaRg2->execute([':codPensum'=>$_POST['txtIdPensum'], ':nombreAsig'=>$_POST['txtAsig']]);
$numeroDeFilas2 = $consultaRg2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($numeroDeFilas2)){ //Si el resultado es la existencia de algún registro con los mismos datos comparados entonces se ejecute el siguiente script.
   ?>.
<script>
    // Creamos la variable "mensaje" e Ingresamos un mensaje a mostrar
    alert("Ya existe una asignatura asociada con ese nombre al pensum actual en la base de datos del sistema.\nSi desea asociar una nueva asignatura al pensum, por favor haga clic en el botón aceptar.");

</script>
    
<?php
} else {
    // Se Procede con la insercion del registro en la DB.
    $sSQLInsert2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbpensumcontenido(Pensum, asignatura, nivel, creditos, totalHoras) VALUES(:Pensum, :Asignatura, :Nivel, :Creditos, :THoras)");
    
    //Se asignan valores a los parametros.
    $sSQLInsert2->bindParam(':Pensum',$_POST['txtIdPensum']);
    $sSQLInsert2->bindParam(':Asignatura',$_POST['txtAsig']);
    $sSQLInsert2->bindParam(':Nivel',$_POST['txtNivel']);
    $sSQLInsert2->bindParam(':Creditos',$_POST['txtCreditos']);
    $sSQLInsert2->bindParam(':THoras',$_POST['txtHoras']);
  
    $sSQLInsert2->execute();
    
    if($sSQLInsert2){
        header('location: ../Pages/Programa.php?id='.$_POST['txtIdPrograma']);
      
    }
}
}
?>

<head>
<link href="../StyleSheet/Estilos_IncludeModalAsignarAsignatura.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../StyleSheet/thema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</script>
</head>
<main class="containerPpal"><br>
      <div id="capafrmRegistrarAsig">
          <div id="tituloAsignarAsignatura" class="ColorTheme">ASIGNAR ASIGNATURA</div>
          <div class="CerrarModalAsignarAsignatura ColorTheme"><a id="btnCerrar" href="javascript:CloseModalAsignarAsignatura();" title="Cerrar" >X</a></div>
          <form id="frmAsignarAsignatura" name="frmAsignarAsignatura" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="text" id="txtIdPensum" name="txtIdPensum" value="<?=$Pensum['idPensum']?>" style="float: right; margin-right: 12px; margin-top:1px;display: none;" readonly>
              <section class="body-form2">
                <div class="campos-BigWidth2"> 
                     <div id="capaetqAsig"> ASIGNATURA *</div>
                      <div id="capatxtAsig">
                          <select name="txtAsig" id="txtAsig" required>
                                <option value="">--- Seleccione ---</option>
                                <?php
                                require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
                                $consultAsig = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbasignatura");
                                $consultAsig->execute();
                                $resultadoAsig = $consultAsig->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach($resultadoAsig as $asignatura){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$asignatura['codigoAsignatura']?>"><?=$asignatura['nombreAsignatura']?></option>
                                  <?php }; ?> 
                            </select>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="campos2"> 
                      <div id="capaetqHoras"> TOTAL HORAS *</div>
                      <div id="capatxtHoras"><input name="txtHoras" type="text" id="txtHoras" required />
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="campos2"> 
                      <div id="capaetqCreditos"> CREDITOS *</div>
                      <div id="capatxtCreditos"><input name="txtCreditos" type="text" id="txtCreditos" required />
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="campos-BigWidth2"> 
                      <div id="capaetqNivel"> NIVEL *</div>
                      <div id="capatxtNivel">
                          <select name="txtNivel" id="txtNivel" required>
                          <option value="">--- Seleccione ---</option>
                                <?php
                                require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
                                $consultaNivel = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbnivelsemestre");
                                $consultaNivel->execute();
                                $resultadoNivel = $consultaNivel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach($resultadoNivel as $nivel){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$nivel['idNivelSemestre']?>"><?=$nivel['nombreNivelSemestre']?></option>
                                  <?php }; ?>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                </div>
                </section>
               <section class="footer-form2">
                 <div class="div-Buttons2">
                    <div id="capabtnCancelar">
                        <input name="btnCancelar" type="reset" id="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar" class="ButtonTheme" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="capabtnAceptar">
                        <input name="btnAceptar" type="submit" id="btnAceptar" value="Aceptar" class="ButtonTheme ColorTheme" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
  </form>  </div>
</main>
    

comparto además el código en el otro modal donde se encuentra CrearPensum.php
<?php
// Incluimos la conexión existente con la DB.
require('../Conexion/conexion.php');
// Se captan en las variables los datos provenientes de los campos del formulario.  

if(!empty($_POST)){

// Se crea la consulta a la tabla para hacer la validación y comparación de los datos.
$consultaRg = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbpensum WHERE nombrePensum = :nombPensum LIMIT 1;");
$consultaRg->execute([':nombPensum'=>$_POST['txtNombre']]);
$numeroDeFilas = $consultaRg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($numeroDeFilas)){ //Si el resultado es la existencia de algún registro con los mismos datos comparados entonces se ejecute el siguiente script.
   ?>.
<script>
    // Creamos la variable "mensaje" e Ingresamos un mensaje a mostrar
    alert("Ya existe un registro con el mismo nombre en la base de datos del sistema.\nSi desea registrar un nuevo pensum, por favor haga clic en el botón aceptar.");

</script>
    
<?php
} else {
    // Se Procede con la insercion del registro en la DB.
    $sSQLInsert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbpensum(nombrePensum, programa) VALUES(:nombPensum, :codProg)");
    
    //Se asignan valores a los parametros.
    $sSQLInsert->bindParam(':nombPensum',$_POST['txtNombre']);
    $sSQLInsert->bindParam(':codProg',$_POST['txtIdPrograma']);

    $sSQLInsert->execute();
    
    if($sSQLInsert){
        header('location: ../Pages/Programa.php?id='.$_POST['txtIdPrograma']);
    
    }
}
}
?>


<head>
<link href="../StyleSheet/Estilos_IncludeModalCrearPensum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../StyleSheet/thema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</script>
</head>
<main class="containerPpal"><br>
      <div id="capafrmRegistrarPensum">
        <div id="tituloCrearPensum" class="ColorTheme">CREAR PÉNSUM</div>
     <div class="CerrarModalCrearPensum ColorTheme"><a id="btnCerrar" href="javascript:CloseModalCrearPensum();" title="Cerrar" >X</a></div>
      <form id="frmCrearPensum" name="frmCrearPensum" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
        
     <input type="text" id="txtIdPrograma" name="txtIdPrograma" value="<?=$Programa['codigoPrograma']?>" style="float: right; margin-right: 12px; margin-top:1px;display: none;" readonly>
          
      <div id="capaetqNombre"> NOMBRE *</div>
        <div id="capatxtNombre"><input name="txtNombre" type="text" id="txtNombre"/>
        </div>
                 
        <div id="containerButtons">
        <div id="capabtnCancelar"> <input name="btnCancelar" type="reset" id="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar" class="ButtonTheme" /></div><div id="capabtnAceptar"><input name="btnAceptar" type="submit" id="btnAceptar" value="Aceptar" class="ButtonTheme ColorTheme" /></div>
          </div>

  </form>  </div>
</main>


Como les manifesté antes ejecutándolos de manera individual funcionan pero al incluir los dos modales en la pagina que los contiene que se llama Programa.php solo me funciona el de CrearPensum.php es decir, sí envía e inserta los datos del formulario, pero el otro el de AsignarAsignatura.php abre el modal pero al enviar los datos manda a una pagina "Not Found".
He intentado quitar en el atributo action del formulario el nombre las paginas donde se procesa el script, que es la misma pagina del formulario pero asi me manda un error en el formulario de CrearPensum.php, el error es de violación en el PDO-exception de que los campos de la base de datos no pueden ser NULL, es como si se tratara de mandar ese formulario tambien, al mismo tiempo que se envia el formulario de AsignarAsignatura.php
Bueno espero me puedan ayudar, con esta explicacion tan larga, mil bendiciones.

Y en la página que contiene estos 2 forms, como los agregas?? con un iframe?

Todo el proyecto se ejecuta dentro de un iframe, pero lo raro es que tengo otras paginas dentro del mismo proyecto que también tienen estructura similar y se ejecutan en un iframe pero no se me había presentado tal situación.

El atributo action="" de los formularios está vacío. Intentaste colocando los nombres de los php en ese atributo?

Si claro, incluso al principio tenia los nombres de los php en el action de los formularios, pero allí me mandaba a la pagina not found cuando intentaba enviar el formulario desde el php AsignarAsignatura.php por esa razón fue que plantee mi inconveniente en este post. actualmente he estado intentando otras cosilla pero no he obtenido buenos resultados.

Dos modales, aparte de la confusión,  son pésimos desde el punto de vista de la Experiencia de Usuario. Si usas Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript tú puedes enviar y recibir cosas entre cliente y servidor mostrando u ocultando, integrados en la misma página lo que serían esos modales.
